# unexpectedly some of my project files are marked with red X sign

Tags: java, android, eclipse

the java file and a file titled `styles.xml` of one of my projects on eclipse became marked with red "X" sign, even eclipse can not reconize lots of classes such as `startActivityForResult` and `getApplicationContext`.

This project was working properly till I once run eclipse I found such mistakes. But When I tried to inspect the reason, I found that `\appcombat_v7_5` is missing.
the `\appcombat_7_5` i found it when i cheched the properties of my project there is a section called `android`, it is the second item on the left in the properties window. If the absence of this file is the real problem, so how can i recover it? if not, how to fix these errors?

stylesXML:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is using [v7 appcompat library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7) to allow more features compatible back to Android 2.1 (API level 7).

Both your issues seems to indicate that "v7 appcompat library" project is not opened/loaded in Eclipse.

If "appcompat_v7_5" project is already on the workspace, just open the project. After that, clean your project if necessary.

If not, you have to re-import the project:

1. Go to File - Import...
2. Choose Android - Existing Android Code Into Workspace, then press Next.
3. Browse to your Android SDK folder, ../extras/android/support/v7/appcompat. Check "Copy projects into workspace", then press Finish.
4. If the imported project doesn't have the same name, you have to re-configure your project to use the new library instead of the old one.
5. Right-click your project, choose Properties, go to Android.
6. Remove the old "appcompat_v7_5" library, then add the new library (ex. "android-support-v7-appcompat"). Press OK and clean if necessary.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but at the point when I import the appcompat from the SDK folder, in this window eclipse shows a redX sign on the top saying "select at least one project" and when I select the the project even the "next" button is not active it is disabled you can not press it

Comment: @user3541771 have you already solved your problem? You just need to press "Finish", not "Next" since there is no next step. (this is the only step)